# Understand PS1 environment variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, prompt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Stackoverflow, I just saw a question concerning the `PS1` environment variable, which is responsible for the Linux terminal prompt.

My prompt looks as follows:

```
username@PORT-usr:/dir
```

- `username` is the username I use when logging into my WSL.
- `PORT-usr` is the name of my laptop.
- `/dir` is my current directory.

My `PS1` environment variable looks as follows:

```
Prompt>echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Trying to execute this does not work:

```
Prompt>echo $($PS1)
\[\e]0;\u@\h:: command not found

Prompt>echo echo $(\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot...)
e]0: command not found
u@h:: command not found
32m]u@h[033[00m]:[033[01: command not found
34m]w[033[00m]$: command not found
```

What is the syntax of the used `$PS1` variable and what command can I use to learn to understand this syntax?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I see something in UNIX I don't understand and I ask it here, what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `PS1` shell variable (which may or may not be also an environment variable) does not contain a regular shell command. It is expanded into a prompt using a special procedure specific to the variety of shell you're using. It is likely to include special sequences that are not recognized by the plain `echo` command.

Your shell prompt looks like the default for Debian (and possibly related distributions). Debian's default shell for regular user accounts is `bash`, so you should look at the `PROMPTING` chapter of `man bash`, or [chapter 6.9: *Controlling the Prompt*](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-prompting) of the Bash Reference Manual.

To understand any embedded terminal control codes, you might have to also refer to the appropriate documentation for your terminal emulator, like [the reference of Xterm control sequences](https://www.x.org/docs/xterm/ctlseqs.pdf).

Here's how your current prompt will be interpreted:

```
\[ ... \]     encapsulates any terminal control codes that will not result in
              any visible output on the prompt line

\e]0;         Xterm control code to set terminal window title and icon name
\u@\h: \w     expands to window title <username>@<hostname>: <workdir>
\a            indicates the end of terminal window title / icon name string
\]            end of encapsulation

${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}
              if variable $debian_chroot is defined, adds text
              "(<contents of $debian_chroot>)" to the prompt

\[            encapsulates terminal control codes, see above
\033[01;32m   set bold output with green foreground color
\]            end encapsulation

\u@\h         expands to "<username>@<hostname>" in the prompt

\[            encapsulates terminal control codes, see above
\033[00m      reset to normal output
\]            end encapsulation

:             outputs a ":" character

\[            encapsulates terminal control codes, see above
\033[01;34m   set bold output with blue foreground color
\]            end encapsulation

\w            outputs the current working directory

\[            encapsulates terminal control codes, see above
\033[00m      reset to normal output
\]            end encapsulation

\$            outputs "$" if a regular user, "#" when UID 0 (root)
```

If the `\[` ... `\]` encapsulation of non-printing characters is not done correctly, you will see errors in line wrapping when the command line becomes longer than the width of your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `PS1` is a language of its own and cannot be just `echo` printed.

To understand it, your only choice is to go to the shell's documentation:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html

Answer (score 1):

If you put your `PS1` definition in a separate file other than your `.bashrc` it will update the prompt each time you save the file.

**Example:**

- In your `.bashrc` file:

  ```bash
  pcmd() {
    _error_value=$?;
    PS1=$(~/.pcmd $_error_value);
  }

  PROMPT_COMMAND=pcmd;
  ```
- And in your home directory the new `.pcmd` file (which must be executable `chmod a+x .pcmd`)

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash
  _error_value=$1;
  _now=$(date +%H:%M);                                                                                       
  _error_r_time=$([ "$_error_value" != "0" ] && echo "[\[\e[1;37m\]>\[\e[1;31m\]$_error_value\[\e[1;37m\]<\[\e[m]\]" || echo "[\[\e[1;37m\]$_now\[\e[m\]");

  echo "[\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[1;36m\]\h\[\e[m\]](\[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[m\])$_error_r_time$ "
  ```